# Getting monthly totals in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 4 columns:

```
bookingdatetime (DateTime)
status (Varchar, with 4 possible entries: 'Open', 'Closed', 'Canceled', and 'Unconfirmed')
quotedprice (Int)
city (Varchar, with 3 possible entries: la, sf, ny
```

I want to get a total amount for reach month for rows that have the status of 'Closed' and 'Open' in a specific city.

I want the output to look like:

```
mm/yy - total of all of that month's quotes for 'Closed' in X city
mm/yy - total of all of that month's quotes all 4 categories
```

This is what I have now, but it doesn't let me do the second output mentioned above:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, "%m/%y") AS mmyy,
SUM(quotedprice) as revenue
FROM `reservations`
WHERE city = 'oc' and status = "Closed"
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y'), YEAR(bookingdatetime)
ORDER BY YEAR(bookingdatetime), DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y')
```

But I want to be able to get potential (all 4 categories, not just 'Closed') sales as well, so how would I do that?

Comment: First you claim `status` has 4 possible entries. In your SQL your are referring to more than 4 possible values for the field `status`.  Be clear about this sort of things, it might get a better answer!.   Now for the question: What is you add `SUM(quoteprice)` to your query ?

Comment: That was an older version of the database. I will edit it to reflect that. I don't follow the question...

Comment: `SUM(status IN ('Open', 'Closed') AND city = 'LA') AS fulfilledreservations_in_LA`

Comment: @Akina - I changed the question a bit - can you help?

Comment: Create a fiddle with some sample data. Show desured result for this data with its logic explaination. PS. Your query do not match the structure described above (`pickuploc` field is not described).

Comment: Sorry, pickuploc is last gen's version of city

Comment: @Akina - I rewrote my question to be more clear.

Comment: Are your 'rows' actually'columns'?

Comment: Yes sorry - brain fart. That should be more clear.

Comment: @tony: Take a look at this example, it shows how to solve your 'problem'. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168540/case-when-with-group-by

Comment: Can any of you look at my answer and explain that to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Luuk's comment this seems to do it, is this the best way to do it?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, "%m/%y") AS mmyy,
SUM(quotedprice) as potentialrevenue,
SUM(CASE WHEN status='Confirmed' THEN quotedprice ELSE 0 END) AS revenue
FROM `reservations`
WHERE city = 'la'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y'), YEAR(bookingdatetime)
ORDER BY YEAR(bookingdatetime), DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y')
```

Can someone explain to me what "ELSE 0 END" does? I'm not familiar with that...